# Using sum(x:y) to create a new variable/vector from existing values in R

Tags: r, sum

I am working in R with a data frame d:

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B")
eventcounter <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
numberofevents <- c(3,3,3,2,2)
d <- data.frame(ID, eventcounter, numberofevents)

> d
  ID eventcounter numberofevents
1  A            1              3
2  A            2              3
3  A            3              3
4  B            1              2
5  B            2              2
```

where `numberofevents` is the highest value in the `eventcounter` for each `ID`.

Currently, I am trying to create an additional vector `z <- c(6,6,6,3,3)`.
If the `numberofevents == 3`, it is supposed to calculate `sum(1:3)`, equally to `3 + 2 + 1 = 6`.

If the `numberofevents == 2`, it is supposed to calculate `sum(1:2)` equally to `2 + 1 = 3`.

Working with a large set of data, I thought it might be convenient to create this additional vector
by using the sum function in R `d$z<-sum(1:d$numberofevents)`, i.e.

```
sum(1:3) # for the rows 1-3
```

and

```
sum(1:2) # for the rows 4-5.
```

However, I always get this warning:

```
Numerical expression has x elements: only the first is used.
```

Comment: `d$z<-(d$numberofevents+1)*d$numberofevents/2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `ave`

```
 d$z <- with(d, ave(eventcounter, ID, FUN=sum))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(d)[,z:=sum(eventcounter), ID][]
```

Comment: This solution works for me:

> d$z <- ave(d$eventcounter, d$ID, FUN = sum)

Thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try using apply sapply or lapply functions in R.

```
sapply(numberofevents, function(x)  sum(1:x))
```

It works for me.